# Regression to Predict a 'Discrete' Ratio

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I am to build a model $y_i \sim f(X_i, n_i) + error_i$. The regressor $y_i \in [0, n_i]$. $y_i$ and $n_i$ are positive integers.  Each observation $i$ has a different known $n_i$, and $n_i$ varies from 2 to 50 for different observations.

I can transform $y_i$ such that $y'_i=\frac{y_i}{n_i} \in [0, 1]$ and try to model it as a proportion. The problem is that when $n_i$ is small ($n_i=2,3,4,5$), the resulting proportion $y'_i$ is very discrete. For example, when $n_i=3$, the only values possible for $y_i$ are 0,1,2.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how to model?

Comment: If $y_i$ is unknown (as you state), how could you even compute $y_i'$? Can you clarify what you mean by 'unknown' there?

Comment: It's common to use [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) for count proportions, though other [binomial GLMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Binomial_data) are used, such as probit models and cloglog models. Try *logistic regression* as a search term both here and more widely.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. 'Unknown' means the dependent variable is not known at time of prediction. It will be known afterwards.

Comment: Oh, okay -- it's not necessary to specify that you don't know the values you're predicting.

Comment: Is there any comment on the discrete nature of the proportions? For certain data points, $n=2$, and the only valid proportions are $0, /frac{1}{2}, 1$, but for other data points, let's say $n=10$, and the valid proportions are $0, \frac{1}{10}, \frac{2}{10},..,1$. I wonder it makes sense to treat them the same and try to fit with one logistic regression.

Comment: Logistic regression is explicitly for count data of this form. It models the counts as binomial, with known $n$ and with $p$ a logistic function of the linear predictor, $X\beta$ (you can think of that as  $\beta_0+\beta_1x$ if you only have one $x$-variable). Do you have a small data set, or some example data that would be suitable? Alternatively, can you say a little about your $x$-variables (what they measure, typical size etc)?

Comment: In my case, the response is an integer that is not a count. Say we are predicting the position of the elevator. The valid range is between 1 and the number of stories of each building. If two observations are made from two different buildings, one has 5 stories and the other 10 stories, then $y_1 \in [1, 5]$ and $y_2 \in [1, 10]$. Do you think the logistic regression is still appropriate? The actual data is huge and messy. Let me see how I can get a small sample.

Comment: Then how is it a proportion (as per your title)? The critical information in your comment should be in your question.

Comment: If you divide the predicted position of the elevator $y_i$ by the total number of stories $n_i$ (for that observation), you get a ratio $y'_i$.

Comment: It might be less likely to mislead if you don't call that ratio a proportion in your title.